# Static linking using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

I tried to static linking libstdc++-6 and libgcc_s_seh-1.I'm using Clion who use cmake. I'm using SFML but it's not necessary that it's dynamically linked.

Thanks

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(Game_Project)
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "Game_Project")

# Enable debug symbols by default
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "")
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mwindows")
endif()
# (you can also set it on the command line: -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -s")

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SFML-2.2/cmake/Modules/" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

set(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR src)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS src/*.cpp)

#Find any version 2.X of SFML
#See the FindSFML.cmake file for additional details and instructions
set(SFML_ROOT "SFML-2.2")
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} include)

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SRCS})

if(SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
endif()

install(TARGETS ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: what is your actual question/problem/error? "it's not necessary that it's dynamically linked." does this mean it could be linked statically **or** dynamically? if yes, why try to link statically anyway?

Comment: I would like that lib of gcc are statically linked, for SFML they can be dynamically.

Comment: again, what is the problem you ran into? any error messages? what does not work as you expect it to?

Comment: With this actual cmake the executable is bigger, but it still needs libgcc_s_seh-1.dll and libstdc++-6.dll. They are not statistically linked even if it's seems to add it into the executable. Output size without static : 62 ko with 692 ko.

Comment: so you are on windows then? which compiler? you might want to set the same flags as listed here: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-September/051966.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you link dynamically against SFML, which in turn links dynamically against libstdc++, your application will still require the so/dll files for libstdc++ because of SFML.

Think of the SFML.dll as a separate executable. That executable has a dynamic runtime dependency on libstdc++. You cannot get rid of that, because SFML has already been linked and there is no way to have it point to the part of libstdc++ that is statically linked to your executable instead.

The only way to get rid of the dependency is to make sure that all components link statically against the library in their linking phase.

The important thing to note here is that static libraries are of no concern for this. Static libraries never pass through the linker (think of them as a bunch of packed together object files), so it is the top-level executable or dynamic library pulling them in that determines how they link against the standard library.

So if you were to build SFML as a static library instead that is then pulled in by your executable, which is configured to statically link against libstdc++, the problem would disappear as well.